# How to create a patch to master from my remote branch?

Tags: git, patch, gerrit

Currently we use patches to commit new work in gerrit.

I already pushed all my work to my remote branch.

And If I used `git push origin <my_local>:remote` to create a patch, I always get `"no new changes"`.

So is there a good way to create a patch including all the difference between my remote branch and master? Working like a Pull request?

Comment: `git push` doesn't create patches.

Comment: @phd in fact it does. we are using that to creat patches for code review

Comment: `git push` doesn't create patches. It pushes commits (with attached objects like trees and files) and updates references. Gerrit displays these commits as diffs (patches) but it's only display, not real patches.

Comment: @phd thanks for clarification. So is there a way to solve my issues above?

Comment: I don't understand the question so no answer. Gerrit, remote branches, patches… I'm complete confused, sorry. I know Git, Gerrit, repositories, commits and pushes. I can create patches from a local repository. But the question is hard to understand.

Comment: yeah. I also can create a patch from my local repo. But my problem is I already pushed my local repo to my remote branch. Or there will be no problem doing it.

Comment: How do you create patches from the repo?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to rebase your local branch with remote master to have the difference.

```
git fetch
git checkout <my_local>
git rebase -p origin/master
git show
```

once you have the difference you can reset your local branch with the remote branch to get back the original state

```
git reset --hard origin/<my_local>
```

Comment: Thanks I also tried rebase onto master, but failed. And I finally solved it by creating a new  clean branch based on master, then merged some minor change, git push it to a new patch, then merged my working branch back, then pushed to the patch.